# A question about initilizing a reference that refers to a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, initialization

We know that in C++ we can initialize a reference with an object/variable of the type the reference refers to. For example, we can use an int variable to initialize a reference to int:

```
int i;
int& r=i;
```

But the situation becomes confused when it comes to reference to pointer. Suppose I need to define a reference to a pointer:

```
int* & r
```

To initialize it, we need to assign `r` a pointer to int. The following code works (continue with the above code):

```
int* p = &i;
int* & r = p;
```

But the following code causes a compiling error even though the right side of = is indeed a pointer to int:

```
int* & r = &i;
```

The error message is:

> 'initializing': cannot convert from 'int *' to 'int *&'.

Why? Why the compiler can covert from `int` to `int&` but cannot convert from `int *` to `int *&`? Why I can initialize with `p` but not with `&i`? Aren't they the same?

PS: I am using Visual Studio 2015 on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us use another compiler, and see if it makes more sense:

> error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'int*&' to an rvalue of type 'int*'

This diagnostic explains the problem better. `int* &` is an lvalue reference type. `&i` is an rvalue expression. As the error explains, non-const lvalues cannot be bound to rvalue expressions.

> Aren't [`p` and `&i`] the same?

They are not the same. `p` is an id-expression. Id-expressions of variables are lvalues.

`&p` expression is the unary `&` operator. The result of the operator is a prvalue.

Comment: I see. So I should write `int* && r = &i;`. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @user5280911 You *could* write that. I don't know why should, or why wou'd want to.

Answer (score 0):

&p is a constant by fact. It's simpy a number of the memory cell(s) where p value is saved. So, you can't inintalize the non-constant reference with a constant.